# Time-indexed "array" of time spans

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

I have a list of objects that have durations,

```
ProcedurePart
  Start: double
  Stop: double
  Instructions: string
```

they occur sequentially after each other:

```
stepOne                   stepTwo                      stepThree
Start: 0.0                Start: 1.56                  Start: 5.443
Stop: 1.56                Stop: 5.443                  Stop: 10.9
"Take the dinglebop"      "Smooth it with shleem"      "Push it through the gru...
```

I want to pull out items using a timestamp, the item retrieved should be the step within which that timestamp falls.

E.g., for the above sequence:

```
sequence[0.0] = stepOne
sequence[1.0] = stepOne
sequence[1.56] = stepTwo
sequence[2.578281] = stepTwo
sequence[10.0] = stepThree
```

The precision is only limited by the data-type (C#'s `double`), and because times are continuous I can't create a look-up table using all possible discrete input values.
Is there a data structure that can store this sequence and allow for anything better than O(log(N)) look-up times (better than binary search)?

Comment: What about using a normalized `DateTime` instead of `double`, maybe with a custom comparator?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how will that allow for faster than O(logN) look up?

Comment: Why do you need better than binary search algorithm? How many steps are you expecting? Billions? And even in such case, having 5 000 000 000 steps, binary search would need ~30 iterations at worst, which is pretty much nothing.

Comment: @Andy I don't expect that many steps, but I will be "indexing" (using different times) lots and lots of times. 30 iterations for billions is a good point though, I honestly hadn't thought of it. I was just excited by the theory behind a possible fast algorithm for this.

Comment: There's a valid reason why nobody really pursued any other search algorithm for sorted data (which can be achieved in your case) besides binary search, because binary search is pretty much already the perfect solution. Even with trillions of sorted records, a record can be found within milliseconds (or faster, depending on the hardware). I really doubt you'd ever need anything better than that.

Comment: Create a array of time step cells. Add each timespan to every cell whose time step intersects. Each cell represents all intersecting time spans. Tada a time based hash table. If you make it so that it refers to the location in a sorted dataset, this can be used to quickly find top and bottom of a range. Of course this doesn't replace binary search, just a way to get near O(1) access. Just pay up in terms of memory.

Comment: @Kain0_0 "time step cells" .... theoretically infinite memory usage?

Comment: Depends on what duration you are wanting fast lookup for. But yes it gets larger, with more time. So does any store of data to which more elements are added. Alternately pull out a trick from hash tables, and wrap it around. Its not like you are still creating time spans for ten years ago? Push them on top, anything recent is fast to lookup. Anything older takes a bit longer. You can also use standard growable hashing techniques to expand/shrink the array.